# Admob for Unity: clarification on use needed

Tags: unity, scripting, plugin, advertisements, admob

I'm following [this documentation](https://developers.google.com/admob/unity/start) by Google on how to integrate Admob ads into my game and I'm confused because of the following:

This documentation says I build by game and then I mess around with ads. (Section Unity plugin API tells me how to add ads and that's after the build instruction). Shouldn't it be vice versa? That I place those ads and build last?

Or, if I really do build first, where do I add those ads?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's actually a mess.

`Unity Ads` and `Google Ads` are two different systems and it's still recommended (from my and other users experience) to use `Google Admob`, because it simply gives you more money.

In order to have working ads, you have to:

1. Add them through the code
2. Add the app to `Google Play` without testing the ads (app may be in alpha-beta phase, don't worry, it won't be public)
3. Add the app to the `AdMob` console ([https://apps.admob.com/v2/home](http://AdMob))
4. Create ads in the `AdMob` console (video, static, banners) and get their keys.
5. Put ads keys into the code (see below)

When you have ad ID's, you put them here:

```
using GoogleMobileAds.Api;
…
private void RequestBanner()
{
    #if UNITY_EDITOR
        string adUnitId = "unused";
    #elif UNITY_ANDROID
        string adUnitId = "INSERT_ANDROID_BANNER_AD_UNIT_ID_HERE";
    #elif UNITY_IPHONE
        string adUnitId = "INSERT_IOS_BANNER_AD_UNIT_ID_HERE";
    #else
        string adUnitId = "unexpected_platform";
    #endif
}
```

as mentioned on the website you provided.

Then, you can test your app, even by building in `Unity` and uploading directly to the phone/tablet. Remember to put ad's ID's to the code. You'll have your ads working.

Comment: Thanks for the input, tomorrow I'll check it out. 
But before that, by registering etc etc does that sync with my bank account? so I get the income and can pay the taxes too?
By the way yes I plan to use Google's solution. I didn't hear much good about Unity's ads.

Comment: In order to publish apps on `Google Play`, you have to pay `25$`. To run ads, you pay nothing. When you want to get the money you earned - you provide your card/paypal or something and they give you the money. I don't know how taxes work through `Play`, I don't pay taxes, and that's why I'll go to jail soon. I'm not sure if `Google` does that automatically.

Comment: Well I live in the European Union where it is automatic, so I don't have to worry :D As for you, I highly recommend getting it sorted out if you don't live around here. 
So the money just accumulates and when I want to, I get that money? Does this "buffer" have a limit there? Or not, because it's just numbers?

Comment: Yeah, I live in EU aswell. I think it does it automatically. When I got my first item-purchase for 3$ they gave me 1.30$ of total income ;O It's because of taxes and probably - Google's fee. I think that there's a limit you have to pass before getting the money. I'm sure it's 100$ on Unity Ads, not sure about Google. It gets calculated once a month.

Comment: By the way that 25$ is per upload, or only once?

Comment: Once. During google play developer console registration. For iOS, you have to pay 100$~ per year.

Comment: That ain't even much (for android). For iOS, well yeah. Maybe later.